# Moment.js + TypeScript. Cannot find name moment

Tags: module, typescript, momentjs

I develope web application with knockout in VisualStudio. I just installed knockout via bower, included d.ts file in project, included script to html page and now i can get access to `ko`.

Now i try to use moment.js. Like with knockout: install, include d.ts, include script to page and i get an error `cannot find name 'moment'`. Adding reference to d.ts does not help, `import * as moment from 'moment'` get an error `can not find module moment`.

I know that it's a stupid problem, but i can't fix it. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I used bower for getting moment.js (v 2.13) and (at least) for this version there was wrong `.d.ts` file in loaded bunch of files. You just have to get correct `.d.ts` file and everything will be OK.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What I'd recommend is using some tool for managing your definitions. Some popular options (you don't need both, just pick one):

1. `tsd` - `npm i -g tsd`
2. `typings` - `npm i -g typings`

These work in a similar fashion as package managers. You can install your definitions like npm/bower installs your dependencies.

Once you have one of these installed, go to your project and install moment + its definition

```
npm install moment --save
```

And one of these:

```
tsd install moment --save
typings install moment --save --ambient
```

Both of these will create a folder with your definitions in it (both call it typings), and both have an "umbrella" definition file in it, which you should reference in the entry point of your application (first is for tsd, second for typings):

```
/// <reference path="typings/tsd.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="typings/index.d.ts" />
```

After this is done, you can use moment (or any other module) as you would:

```
import * as moment from 'moment'
moment.isDate("I'm not a date")
```

I suggest checking out these:

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd
https://github.com/typings/typings

Comment: As of TypeScript 2.0 this can be done without `tsd` or `typings`, see: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/

Comment: I'm not convinced this is the best (or at least not the only) answer - Raul's answer below fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 14):

In my case, finally get this error solved by doing the following:

1. Adding this option `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,` in the `compilerOptions` section of the `tsconfig.json` file (**EDITED**: As the [moment doc](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/typescript/). sais in the **Note:** `If you have trouble importing moment, try add "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true in compilerOptions in your tsconfig.json file.`)
2. Also add `"moduleResolution": "node"` in the same `compilerOptions` section. (Found this option looking around the web)
3. Importing moment module like this `import * as moment from 'moment';`

Comment: Thanks. I'd found (1) in the moment documentation but, on its own, it wasn't enough - once I'd done (2) it started working.

Comment: @BartRead I have edited the answer and provided the link to the moment doc when it is said that if it doesn't work try `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true`

Answer (score 7):

This seems to solve the problem for me (the other solutions in this thread didn't work):

`import * as moment from 'moment/moment.js';`

I still seem to be getting the correct typescript definitions even referencing the js file directly. I suspect the reason is that the 'moment' folder under node_modules does not have an index.js file but I'm not a typescript typings/compiler expert.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error today. 
The fix was to downgrade the "moment" package from "2.25.0" to "2.22.1" in package.json

My application is an angular 8 version and "typescript": "3.5.3

Comment: thanks, I was losing my mind about this. The downgrade workaround works for me

Answer (score 4):

For me, error comes from moment version 2.25.0.
A workaround for the moment is to downgrade to 2.24.0.

In moment@2.25.0 - package.json :

```
"typesVersions": {
    ">=3.1": {
      "*": [
        "ts3.1-typings/*"
      ]
    }
  }
```

But folder 'ts3.1-typings' does not exist. If your typescript version is 3.1 or higher you'll have error :

```
Cannot find module 'moment'
```

Github issue : https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/5486

Comment: We had this occur as well.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding the below code, it worked for me

```
import * as MomentD from "node_modules/moment/moment.d";
```

Comment: Worked for me: `import moment, { Moment } from "moment/moment.d";`

Comment: @amirnissim : Your comment must be an answer as it worked for me. Thank you :)

Comment: How about the npm dependencies that are using moment and making changes to their import statements won't be a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

In angular you can do:

```
declare const moment: any;
```

after imports.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it to add "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true property in tsconfig.app.json file and remove "angularCompilerOptions": { "enableIvy": false}. also set below dependecy in package.json "moment": "^2.28.0", "ngx-daterangepicker-material": "4.0.1", "tslib": "^2.0.0",

Answer (score 0):

Declare below in the typings.d.ts file which needs to be created at the root level of the project.

```
declare module 'moment' {
    const moment: any;
    export = moment
}
```