# ASP MVC VS2017 AdminLTE 2.4.8 Can't build can't locate TypeScript

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, typescript

I want to use the latest AdminLTE. But when I set up manage to bind my project with AdminLTE. I can't build successfully and I get can't find the module in a full calendar TYPE Script. Please help. I searched everywhere and tried out the following solutions but it doesn't work

1. Tried to install npm https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/the-future-of-declaration-files-2/

and

[Moment.js + TypeScript. Cannot find name moment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37360931/moment-js-typescript-cannot-find-name-moment)

2. [VS 2017 Cannot find moment,JQueryPromise,JQueryEventObject & JQueryAjaxSettings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48781527/vs-2017-cannot-find-moment-jquerypromise-jqueryeventobject-jqueryajaxsettings)
   Suggested something but I don't get it.

[image: Type Script Error.]

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Do not use `d.ts` file. Delete `d.ts` file and use `.js` file.